# Why does this 8 bit binary (100000010) stayed the same using XOR operation when masking?

Tags: math, bit-manipulation, bit

I apologize if this is in the wrong section. As for my question, I do understand the AND and OR masking operations. I am quite confused why does 10000010 have the same mask's value as the original value? We were asked to toggle the bits 1 and 7. If I do understand XOR right, I'd toggle 1 to 0 and 0 to 1. Why the mask of 10000010 isn't 00000000? I appreciate any helpful explanation regarding this question.

I have this one class asynchronous, so asking my prof during class time is not possible. I have emailed my professor already, but he hasn't replied for the past few hours.

Comment: What do you mean by "the mask of 10000010"?

Comment: @harold This was an example value for us to determine its mask by using XOR operator. We had to toggle 1 and 7, so those two '1's' in 10000010. Unfortunately, we were only given one example, so this example was really confusing for me.

Comment: OK, anyway can you show the code

Comment: @harold I am not working on any code nor I have one to begin with.

Comment: Then what are you doing? If you're flipping the bits by hand, you can make the result whatever you want it to be

Comment: @harold  I was working on this problem on paper, so no code was made for this. I was only given a value and asked to determine the mask. Basically, it doesn't matter if we flip them or not when using XOR operator? I guess this part wasn't very well explained to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XOR is a function that takes 2 inputs and apply an "EXCLUSIVE OR" (XOR) meaning it equals `1` only if the inputs are different:

```
0 XOR 0 = 0
0 XOR 1 = 1
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
```

That means that bit to bit you have:

```
10000010 XOR 00000000 = 10000010
```

If you want to get `00000000`, you should go:

```
10000010 XOR 10000010 = 00000000
```

Comment: This is helpful. I didn't know that I could go two ways to get the answer and the mask. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: No problem, don't hesitate to accept the answer if that solved your problem.